# liftweb - change base url

Tags: scala, tomcat, lift

I have a website developed with Liftweb, which runs on tomcat 6 on port 8080 behind an apache webserver on port 80. The apache server binds the / path to the tomcat application folder (which look like /liftweb-application/).

Unfortunately, lift adds automatically the liftWeb.js in my HTML code with the tomcat application folder as prefix. 
Thus, instead of www.mydomain.com/ajax_request/liftAjax.js, I have www.mydomain.com/liftweb-application/ajax_request/liftAjax.js which doesn't exist.

My question is : is there a way to change the base url from www.mydomain.com/liftweb-application/ to www.mydomain.com/ ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to deploy your WAR file as the ROOT context in Tomcat.  This seems like a pretty decent explanation: http://benhutchison.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/how-to-configure-tomcat-root-context/